# Unable to call OpenCV's Mat::zeros with size and type parameters

Tags: c++, opencv, compiler-errors, overloading

I'm trying to create a `Mat` with the same size and type of another one. All elements of the new `Mat` should be zero, so I tried the `Mat::zeros(size, type)` function, defined as:

```
static MatExpr zeros(Size size, int type);
```

This is my code. Assume I already have a `Mat g` (created via `imread`):

```
Mat h = Mat::zeros(g.size, g.type());
```

This will give me a compiler error, complaining that:

**No matching function for call to 'zeros'**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the type of `g.size`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You've stumbled upon one of the quirks of `cv::Mat`. The `size` field does not return a `cv::Size`, but rather a `Mat::MSize` structure. This `MSize` can be converted to a `cv::Size` by calling its `operator()`.

You need to call like this:

```
Mat h = Mat::zeros(g.size(), g.type());
```

Comment: Thank you. Any other quirks I should be aware of? ;-)